# What version? dell inspiron 910 8GB

Tags: lubuntu, dell, ssd, inspiron, versions

I'm new to Ubuntu and planning to install it on my Dell Inspiron 910, because in Windows XP some random updates ate all my 8GB storage (SSD).

Even after stripping down XP to the bone, I'm unable to install any of the updates due to no storage space available. Therefore, I've decided to install Ubuntu instead.

After doing research, I came across various versions of Ubuntu.

First it was 32bit / 64bit. And then, I found Lubuntu, Xubuntu, etc. I have tried Lubuntu from a live disk which did not help me to connect with WiFi (known problem I assume). After some reading I realized, there were different specifications of the Ubuntu versions, especially about disk space that each version requires. In my case, it is pretty important. So, given the fact I only have 8GB SSD.

Which one will be most suitable for me?

Comment: @Edwin Don't you have any separate drives? You can install Ubuntu in 8 GB but where would you keep your files?

Comment: Wifi on my old mini 9 needed the proprietary Broadcom driver. I think Ubuntu (just regular Ubuntu on my 16GB SSD) detected the hardware and asked whether I wanted the proprietary driver.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your system specification I can only speculate which distribution would be suitable for you. If you want an Ubuntu / Debian based OS then you could try [Linux Mint](http://www.linuxmint.com/).

Their [system requirements](http://blog.linuxmint.com/?p=2366) for their latest version, needs about 5GB so it would still leave you with some room to install a few apps, but not a lot.

I would recommend installing the [Xfce version](http://www.linuxmint.com/download.php) (last one in the list) as its a bit more lightweight.

Also again, guessing the hardware is old **only use 32-bit of any distribution** as 64-bit is only really for newer machines.

Hope this helps and let me know how it all goes.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed Lubuntu 32-bit once a 8GiB SSD disk in a netbook.

Lubuntu needs around 2.4GiB space. You can install the programs you need (libre office, etc) and clean up the cache and remove any old kernels, this will consume no more than 5GiB. So you are left with 3GiB for other stuff.

It may be prudent to try and see if the 32bit Lubuntu liveCD runs on your hardware, before you install it.

Answer (score 0):

That computer has an Atom N270, which is [32bit only](http://ark.intel.com/products/36331/).  If you didn't get WiFi with the Lubuntu LiveCD, try it with a full Ubuntu LiveCD (or here's a windows tool for [making a LiveUSB key](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/)), or try a different Ubuntu version.